# Percentage in sql query, invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql, sql

For some reason I'm having an issue getting this query to work.

I'm trying to get a percentage on line 3 where I take the number of records where `curdate()` is less than `d.next_call_date + 7 days` divided by total contacts, i.e. `count(*)` and then group by the user. I've done this for just a count of records but when I tried this for the percentage I keep getting an error 1111 invalid use of group function.

If I remove line 3 it works fine so I know the error is there.

Is it obvious to someone what I've done wrong?

```
select 
 c.user as UserID,
 sum(curdate() < (d.next_call_date + interval 7 day ) / count(*)) as upToDate
From jfi_dealers.contact_events c
join Jackson_id.users u
on c.user = u.id
join jfi_dealers.dealers d
on c.dealer_num = d.dealer_num
where c.user = u.id
group by c.user;
```

Comment: Why `c.user = u.id` twice?

Comment: Move the count(*) out from sum.

Comment: Wow I can't believe I missed that! I moved a set of parenthesis earlier and I totally missed that. Thank you, if you want to make an answer I'll accept it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parentheses are in the wrong place, so the `count(*)` is nested in the `sum()`.  But you should be able to eliminate it entirely, using the `avg()` function:

```
select c.user as UserID,
       avg(curdate() < (d.next_call_date + interval 7 day ) ) as upToDate
. . .
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the `count(*)` out from the `sum()`:

```
select 
 c.user as UserID,
 sum(curdate() < (d.next_call_date + interval 7 day )) / count(*) as upToDate
From jfi_dealers.contact_events c
join Jackson_id.users u
on c.user = u.id
join jfi_dealers.dealers d
on c.dealer_num = d.dealer_num
group by c.user;
```

I also deleted the `where` clause, since it only contained a repeated join condition.